# How to convert a shapefile to a grid file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, esri-grid-format

I was wondering whether anyone might be able to tell me in layman's terms how to convert a polygon layer to a Grid file in ArcGIS 10.1 or ArcGIS 10.2?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Polygon to raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000030000000) function (which requires Spatial analyst extension).

In the `Value field` property you assign which field should be the base of your grid, e.g. which different values your grid will have.

Don't worry about `Cell assignment type` and `Priority field`, play with them if you don't get the desired result.

Depending on how close you would want to look at your grid, you should set the `Cellsize` parameter differently. A good starting point is 10 m (it will use the same units as your map in general), but decrease if the result looks pixly. I would not recommend going too low on this, since it will greatly increase the file size.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of conversion, you need to choose the attribute field that you want to store in the grid, because a grid can only have one thematic information. This is the **value field** that you need to define.

Knowing that, you can use one of the "[Feature to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000033000000)" tools for the conversion, or in your case maybe [Polygon to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Polygon_to_Raster/001200000030000000/) which is more specific (but you then need the 3D or Spatial Analyst extension, or an advanced licence).

For an output in a GRID format, your output workspace must not be a geodatabase, and you must not write any file extension.

> When not saving to a geodatabase, specify .tif for a TIFF file format,
>   .img for an ERDAS IMAGINE file format, or no extension for a GRID
>   raster format.